# c# datagridview update Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have problem when i try to save changes in database. Am geting exception

> Value cannot be null

Check my code am not shure what is happening

```
public class GrupeArtikala : Form, IGrupeArtikalaView
{
    #region Properties 
    private DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    private DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

    private MySqlConnection conn;
    private MySqlDataAdapter adapter;


    #endregion


    private void GrupeArtikala_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grupeArtikalaGrid.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        GetData("SELECT * FROM grupe");
    }

    private void saveToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Update the database with the user's changes.
        adapter.Update((DataTable)bindingSource1.DataSource);
    }

    private void GetData(string selectCommand)
    {
        try
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);

            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, conn);

            // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
            // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
            // update the database.
            MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

            // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            grupeArtikalaGrid.DataSource = dt;

            // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
            grupeArtikalaGrid.AutoResizeColumns(
                DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**StackTrace**

> at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable)
>   at MVPLearing.GrupeArtikala.saveToolStripButton_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in
>   E:\Radni\C#\WinForms-Ucenje\MVPLearing\MVPLearing\GrupeArtikala.cs:line
>   308    at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key,
>   EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs
>   e, ToolStripItemEventType met)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e,
>   ToolStripItemEventType met)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)    at
>   MVPLearing.Program.Main() in
>   E:\Radni\C#\WinForms-Ucenje\MVPLearing\MVPLearing\Program.cs:line 19
>   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: maybe just `adapter.Update(dt);`

Comment: Now i dont get any exception but changes is not saved to database

Comment: not sure if it will help, but remove or comment out `grupeArtikalaGrid.DataSource = bindingSource1;`

Comment: You were getting the error before because you never set `bindingSource1.DataSource` to anything. For example `bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: I set `bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;` inside `GetData` method and again am getting the some

Comment: Obviously `adapter.Update((DataTable)bindingSource1.DataSource);` will result in an argument exception. Because you should assign `dt` to `bindingSource1.DataSource`. Currently `bindingSource1.DataSource` is null because you didn't assign anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose one of the fields is marked as "not null" in the data table (memory table), but it is null in the database.

Check the setup of your data table and allow null in all columns that are populated from nullable columns in the database table(s).

Comment: All fields i set to `null` only ID primary key has not null and AI and again is the some

Comment: What is the type of the exception?

Comment: This looks like `bindingSource1.DataSource` is null, since that is passed as the argument to the method. Otherwise, you may inspect the call stack inside the exception and see which exact method was invoked with the null argument.